# Table View Covers Tab Bar on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I'm writing an iPad app with a UITabBarController.  At the moment it has two buttons.  When the user presses the first button I bring up a table view.  When the use selects a row I switch to another table view.  Trouble is, when the second tabel view comes up, the tab bar is no longer visible.   I feel like I need to add the second table view as a subview of the first to keep from covering the tab bar.  Help!

Comment: Can you paste some code where you are pushing the 2nd TableView? In particular, whether you are using a NavigationController or just using Modal display.

Comment: Out on the road at the moment, but I can tell you it's a [self present modal...] that displays the view covering the tab bar.  If I use a [self.navigationcontroller push...] it doesn't display at all.  Home in an hour.  Will post code then.

Comment: This code does not show the view:

Comment: [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];

Comment: Sorry can't figure out how to post doe here.  I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: This code shows the frame but covers the tab bar:

Comment: self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

Comment: You cannot use modalView. This sits on top of the view stack over everything (including TabBar). [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES]; does not work if you do not have a NavigationController in your view stack. 

You must follow the view stack order below (ignore the UINavigationController on the top as that is not 100% necessary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm about to sleep, I'm going to make some assumptions, post a solution that I hope helps you out :)

Firstly, I believe you've got a

```
UINavigationController
-> UITabBarController
   -> UITableViewController
```

stack.

Now, what happens if you do push the new view onto the stack is that it will use the UINavigationController that exists at the top of the stack. So what you get now is

```
UINavigationController
-> UITableViewController2
-> UITabBarController
   -> UITableViewController
```

which hides your TabBar, as you said. You can't use a Modal view either because that will sit on top of everything, and prevent all other views from getting interaction.

So, what you actually need is another UINavigationController within your UITabBarController, like so

```
UINavigationController
-> UITabBarController
   -> UINavigationController 
      -> UITableViewController
```

So when you push the 2nd view, you will get this

```
UINavigationController
-> UITabBarController
   -> UINavigationController
      -> UITableViewController2
      -> UITableViewController
```

Hope this helps you out.